# Discontinuity of the magnetic field $\vec B(r,\theta , \phi )$ $=$ $\frac {aB_0}{r\sin \theta}\vec e_{\phi}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, classical-electrodynamics

I got the magnetic field given as following:

> $\vec B(r,\theta , \phi )$ $=$ $\frac {aB_0}{r\sin \theta}\vec
>  e_{\phi}$ $\;$ for $\;$ $\theta \gt [0,\pi /4]$ $\;$ and $\;$ $\vec
> B(r,\theta , \phi )$ $=$ $0$ $\;$ for $\;$ $\theta \lt [0,\pi /4]$,
>
> where $a \gt 0$ is a constant and we are using the spherical
>   coordinates.

The question is, where the field in infinite and where it is discontinuous, because I confuse those terms here.

The $rotB = 0$ and I don't have any further information about the conductor, but the current density is going to be infinite (at point) on the conductor surface and zero outside. So when I was calculating the current densities I used the delta function. But If I can use the delta function to see how the current density behaves and its source is the magnetic field, then what are these discontinuous points, like the limit doesn't exist? Because I don't know how to apply it here.

My idea is that if we are aproaching the origin, like ($\theta \to 0$ and $r \to 0$) the magnetic field might be zero, but I don't know what to do with $r$ (or how to view it), but if $\theta \gt [0,\pi /4]$ and $r$ is near zero point, than the field is infinite? Like the function is obviosly discontinuous at $r =0$, but I still don't have the right intuition and I think I am wrong.

Comment: The function is *singular* at $r=0$, and the magnetic field is not zero.  It might be more productive to consider $r\sin\theta$ as one quantity (what distance does it represent?) and deal with the angular limit separately.

Comment: The $y$ axis? So at $r$ the function is discontinuos and I look just at the angular limit?  Like for $\theta \to 0$ we have zero field and for $\theta \to \pi$ we get infinity? Or I really don't know what am I talking about, because that is probably true.

Comment: So I actually say that $r$ must be nonzero to make sense. And for $\theta $ it depends on which angle am I using...?

Comment: Draw a diagram.    The $\phi=0$ plane, spherical coordinates.  Pick an arbitrary point, and label $\theta$ and $r$ for that point.  What then does $r\sin\theta$ represent?  On thing we have to watch out for:   check what $\phi$ and $\theta$ mean.  In physics, $\phi$ is *usually* the azimuthal angle ("longitude"), and $\theta$ is the polar angle ("latitude").  But some authors, especially mathematicians, define them the other way around.  Also: why do you suspect that when $\theta\rightarrow 0$ the field approaches zero?  That's not right.

Comment: Because it's a step function. But not sure.

Comment: But it doesn't include the zero point?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what your comments are responding to!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79049/discussion-between-garyp-and-leif).